# Can you be a werewolf even though you attacked Whiterun?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

During the rebellion questline, I attacked Whiterun with the Stormcloaks and lost the quest to join the Companions, but I really want to become a Werewolf. Is there still a way for me to become a Werewolf?

Comment: When you say you attacking Whiterun, what do you mean by that? Do you just have a bounty? How did you lose the companions guild questline?

Comment: i mean attacking whitetrun with the rebellion

Comment: What do you mean "lost the quest"? Are you saying you were counted as failing a Companions quest?

Comment: I really don't see how this relates to anything....could you be more specific please?

Comment: if there is a rebellion on going(i think you joined Stormcloaks and attacked Whiterun) the quest for joining the companions will be onhold. the same is true if you are to assassinate someone in Solitude in a Dark Brotherhood quest.

Comment: @Studoku he meant no way to get the quest.

Answer (score 4):

The companions do not take sides in the Skyrim civil war. Completing the civil war quest line for either side will not make them hostile, nor will it fail or close off any of their quests.

You may be unable to do some of the quests during the siege of Whiterun because it changes the area. Shortly afterwards, you may also need to travel somewhere else so the area can reset but all you need to do is fast travel anywhere then return to Whiterun.

Answer (score -2):

player.addspell 92c48
Ths will give you Beast Form power and after the first transformation, you will become a werewolf.